# UPDATE Blocking SELECT Of Unrelated Rows

Tags: sql-server

I have `TableA` with `Col1` as the primary key. I am running the following transaction without committing it (for test purposes).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TableA
SET Col3 = 0
WHERE Col2 = 'AAA'
```

In the meanwhile, I run the following query and see that it waits on the first transaction to complete.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Col2 = 'BBB'
```

But the following query returns the results immediately:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE Col1 = '1'
```

So I thought that the second query might need to read rows that have exclusive locks put by the first transaction in order to select rows with `Col2 = 'BBB'`. That's why then I tried to index `Col2` so that a table seek will not be necessary but that did not work either. Second query still waits on the first transaction.

What should be done to prevent `SELECT` from blocking (except the use of `NOLOCK`).

P.S: Transaction isolation level is "Read Committed".

Comment: If the data is locked you can't read it without read uncommitted or nolock. It may be that you are encountering lock escalation where the engine decides to lock the page instead of the just the row. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx

Comment: Add DDL for the table and indexes to your question.

Comment: If it's an entirely different set of rows, you can use the ROWLOCK hint to try and get the optimizer to use row-locks instead of entire table logs (or prevent the engine from escalating the lock up to a table lock). I've had that help in a similar situation, where I knew both the queries AND the updates were operating on exactly one row. Table locks were never necessary in my case.

Comment: My guess is that you don't have a clustered index therefore the rows to update are spread across the data pages and these are being locked by a page lock. I think that the rows where col2 = '1' are on a different page. You could use some of the DBCC commands to check.